# Script to copy a file to a remote host and rename it

Tags: shell-script, rsync, scp, file-transfer

I am trying to come up with a Shell script that can tar a file and copy (scp?) it from Host A to a remote host B at a particular destination `/foo`, and rename it to a particular time format we use let's say YYYY-MM-DD.

Now to add to this functionality let's say there's a file `foo.txt` that is copied from Host A to a path on Host B on a particular date, this of course accomplished by the script. Now in case this script is run twice on the same day, instead of overwriting the existing file on remote Host B this script has to identify that a version already exists on Host B and instead of overwriting it, has to append the timestamp on the file being copied by let's say "1" and hence copy it as a different file.

For example, if `foo.txt` already exists on Remote Host B, the script that's run from Host A should rename the file to `foo.txt.1` and copy it onto the same path on remote host B.

Since it's only one file I am fine using SCP over rsync.

Comment: I would use cron to schedule the task and then this to see if the file exists: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12845206/check-if-file-exists-on-remote-host-with-ssh

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your request, you just need an rsync option: `--backup` (or `-b`).

Taking a look at rsync manpage:

> **-b**, **--backup**
>   With this option, preexisting destination files are renamed as each
>   file is transferred or deleted. You can control where the backup file
>   goes and what (if any) suffix gets appended using the *--backup-dir* and
>   *--suffix* options.

So, if you are planning to transfer the file `foo.txt` to the folder `/foo`, from `Host1` to `Host2`, your command could be:

```
rsync -b --suffix=".$(date +%Y-%m-%d)" -e "ssh -p $SSH_SERVER_PORT" foo.txt remoteuser@Host2:/foo/foo.txt
```

Each time you will copy the file "`foo.txt`" onto `Host2`, you will get a new file "`foo.txt.YYYY-MM-DD`".
Consider using the option `--backup-dir` to keep all backupped versions of your file in the same place.

- Pay attention: you will have just 1 backup copy a day for each file, because of your choice of suffix. If you want to keep "all" backup copies, consider using another suffix option (date `+%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%s` could be an idea)

Comment: I tried doing this, however what I have noticed is that this actually just takes a back of it on the existing server itself and doesn't copy it to the remote server. For example after I run this command, it's just making a backup version of the file in the server I run this command in it doesn't copy it to the remote host that I wanna copy this to.

Comment: Could you paste here your customized line of code (with fake usernames and server addresses) and the output of that using the `-vvv` option? It's really strange this behaviour because of the rsync syntax: (PUSH) rsync [OPTION...] SRC... [USER@]HOST:DEST